# Finding points within radius

Tags: mysql

I was looking up Euclidean formula and Haversine formula but I am still not sure what the best way to do this.

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE antenna (
id INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment,
x INTEGER,
y INTEGER,
z INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY('id')
);
```

I'm trying to make a plugin for the game Minecraft which has a flat world rather than a sphere like the Earth. Each x,y,z represents a single block. And I am not searching for points within miles or kilometers; I am searching points within a distance (e.g. 500 blocks). So I am not sure if I can use Haversine?

Comment: You should be able to use the fact that `(500)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2` - using the distance from your current point as the radius of the sphere.